# how to add an attachment with mailgun

Tags: php, mailgun

How do we add an attachment with mailgun ?   Why can't I find how to do such a basic thing ?  I've tried multiple recipes, and it never works.

For instance :

```
    $msg = $mg->MessageBuilder();
    $msg->setFromAddress($sender_email);
    $msg->addToRecipient($to);
    $msg->setSubject($subject);
    $msg->setTextBody($body);
    $msg->addAttachment('zzz.txt');
$files['attachment'] = array();
$files['attachment'][] = 'zzz.txt';

    $mg->post("{$domain}/messages", $msg->getMessage(), $files);
```

Why the file zzz.txt is not included in the email ?

Why is there absolutely no clear instructions anywhere about how to do this ?

Comment: RTM maybe? https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229656/mailgun-sent-mail-with-attachment

Comment: What do you say ?  I'm not using curl !

Comment: How to add an attachement in the same way as I add the subject or the body ?

Comment: addAttachment method should work, to make sure you have access to zzz.txt, use file_exists function to double check.

Comment: I have access to the file. What's missing in my code ?

Comment: Using both methods (sendmessage and MessageBuilder), I get this : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 26: couldn't open file "zzz.txt" [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandbox8df78f0cdbc646aeb2a46999a8c6def5.mailgun.org/messages'; in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutlage\newsletter\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php:359 Stack trace: #0 .........................